# Why this overshoot in transient?

Tags: circuit-design, control-system, bode-plot, compensation

I am designing a forward converter whose output can be variable from 4V to 30V, 0-5A. This is going to be a pre-regulator for a linear converter. This is the schematic:

[image]

I am using UC3844 controller IC to achieve peak current mode control. This is the transient that I am getting when the circuit starts.

[image]

As you can see there is a small overshoot(640mV) before the output settles at 30V only at the startup. But when there is a step change from 30V to 4.6V and 4.6V to 30V there is no overshoot at all.
.
What can be the reason for this overshoot and how can I avoid it?

This is the AC response at 30V in case you need it:

[image]

Comment: Insufficient plots of input power to explain why slew rate is almost 25 ms on startup , yet only a couple ms on restart from 4.6V  V1? V3?

Comment: Actually I am using a soft start circuit(Rss, Css and Q2) to reduce the inrush current and that's why it is taking time at the startup.

Comment: That Vbe drop must be the reason for the overshoot

Comment: I tried using another transistor but it had no effect on the overshoot. While tinkering I found that reducing the voltage divider resistances reduces the overshoot so I am guessing there is something wrong with how I am connecting the TL431.

Comment: Why do you need the TL431?

Comment: For the voltage reference and the outer voltage control loop. Also since it is widely used it is easily available at a low price. Is TL431 the wrong choice for my purpose?

Comment: it does need a minimum load current to regulate

Answer (score 1):

Overshoot is the symptom of 2 poles with a non zero imaginary part.

640 mV is really little.

I think that a softer start-up could solve the problem.

Comment: I am already using a soft start circuit comprised of Rss, Css and Q2 as cane be seen in top left of schematic. Increasing the startup time further to around 50ms also doesn't solve the problem and overshoot still remains the same(640mV). And about the overshoot, I watched in one the videos of Dave of EEVBlog that in a bench power supply the output should not exceed the set voltage at startup and that's why I want to completely remove it.